# Respond to bluetooth headphones buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bluetooth

I need to capture Buttons on Bluetooth headphones when the app is opened without any media.

I tried the code below but it does not capture anything.
Apparently, this is only for wired headphones use.
I tried everything I can find on the internet but could not make this work.
Do you have some way I can make this work?

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "volume down" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "volume up" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MUTE){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "volume mute" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}
```